# regex just take last value

Tags: php, regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

my problem is when regex get any value it just take last correct one

input

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 6.0.1; SAMSUNG; GT-I8750) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063
```

output i get

```
Android
```

what real output i want

```
Windows Phone 10.0
```

my code

```
function getOS() { 
  global $user_agent;
  $os_platform    = "Unknown OS Platform";
  $os_array       = array(
'/Windows Phone 10.0/i'         =>  'Windows Phone 10',
'/android/i'            =>  'Android',

    );

foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) { 
  if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
    $os_platform  = $value;
  }
}

return $os_platform;
}
```

it replace with last correct match he's get...
i just want take "Windows Phone 10.0" even if it find "Android" in my input.

thanks

Comment: You could always make the test for Windows the last test...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're facing is that the code is overwriting the $os_platform variable with the last match found in the $os_array. To achieve your desired result, you can modify your code to stop searching once a match is found.

```js
function getOS(userAgent) {
  let osPlatform = "Unknown OS Platform";
  const osArray = [
    { regex: /Windows Phone 10\.0/i, value: 'Windows Phone 10' },
    { regex: /android/i, value: 'Android' }
  ];

  for (const item of osArray) {
    if (item.regex.test(userAgent)) {
      osPlatform = item.value;
      break; // Stop searching once a match is found
    }
  }

  return osPlatform;
}

const userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 6.0.1; SAMSUNG; GT-I8750) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063";
const os = getOS(userAgent);
console.log(os); // Output: "Windows Phone 10"
```

Comment: if u tried this input

"Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; LOGAN_Panita_3G; rv:48.0; CAEN) Gecko/48.0 Firefox/48.0 KAIOS/2.5.1.2"

and these regex
'/iOS/i'              =>  'iOS',
'/KAIOS/i'                        =>  'KaiOS',
'/OS\/2/i'                      =>  'OS/2',

you will see the output is => iOS not "KaiOS" 

thats my problem with my code too